# Regular Expression Guidance

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm working on a `C#` project.

I have data like so (csv format):

```
error01="BRE126:Invalid token found.",error02="BRE103:Access has been denied.",error03="BRE102:User must be logged on., info01="some info",warn01="some warning"
```

I want to parse the data and generate a list of errors, info and warnings.

How would the regular expression look to find them?
Is there a better way?

EDIT: I know what to do as far as getting the MatchCollection and working with that, I really just need help on the expression.

Comment: How about using a properties file instead of csv? So it will be like `code=description`

Comment: Sadly that part is not in my control, I am presented with the csv formatted data from a third party restful api.

Comment: Ok, what data you would need or what action you need to take? Will the number of columns be fixed across the rows ?

Comment: no fixed columns, could be any number of errors, or info or warnings.

so far I have error[0-9][0-9]="[^"\r\n]*" for errors, i think i can work with that in 2 steps, but maybe it would be nice to just search the original text 3 times, each time getting the data between the quotes for error, warn and info respectively.

Comment: Not sure how exactly the data going to be used. One way could be to parse the row- split by comma and then split by equal  add as properties if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dict = Regex.Matches(text, @"(.+?)=\""(.+?)\""[, $]*")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: it's ok, i can just use (.+?)="(.+?)" and problem solved. Thanks